# User defined variable not working in Mysql Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to rank the rows based on when was it lasted updated partitioned by category name.

```
$query = "SELECT 
   category_name, 
   topic_title, 
   updated_ts,
   @topic_rank := IF(@current_category = category_name, @topic_rank + 1, 1) AS topic_rank,
   @current_category := category_name AS current_category
FROM topic_master
ORDER BY category_name, updated_ts DESC
                ";
$data = $this->db->query($query);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

This query runs perfectly fine in MySQL and gives me the topic_rank as 1,2,3 and so on.
When I run this in CodeIgniter, I get topic_rank as 1 for all records.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: can you include your error output ?

Comment: There is no error. Query runs fine. Output is all the rows have topic_rank as 1. Somehow i feel the current_category variable is not getting set. The if condition fails always. This exact same code works fine in MySQL workbench.

Comment: The problem is that @current_category is always blank and hence the if condition is not becoming true. I can't understand why the variable is blank. It is as if the value of the variable is erased after it moves to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use codeigniger database methods `result_array()`:

```
$q = $this->db->query($query);
$data = $q->result_array();
```

Comment: The problem is the output of query is wrong. It should increment the rank variable which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternate way to solve this problem. No idea why the user defined variable was not working.

```
select category_name, topic_title as last_topic, updated_ts as last_activity, topic_pri_key as last_topic_id from
                        (
                            select
                                a.category_name, a.topic_title,
                                a.updated_ts, 
                                a.topic_pri_key,
                                count(b.updated_ts)+1 as rank
                            from
                            topic_master a
                            left join
                            topic_master b
                            on a.updated_ts < b.updated_ts and a.category_name = b.category_name
                            group by 1,2,3,4
                        ) a
                        where rank = 1
```